# Connect to remote server and start/stop the Tomcat that's running on that particular server using Ant?

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, jmx

### The purpose is to:

1. **connect** to a remote server maybe via host: ip , port: 8181
2. **stop** Tomcat that's running on that server
3. **deploy** a .war file
4. **restart** Tomcat

Underneath are few approaches I have taken so far to achieve this task:

### Approaches taken so far:

I have looked at the following solutions but none of them worked for me:

1. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/start-tomcat-server-remotely-824472/  --Not efficient
2. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Start_an_Existing_Application
3. http://raibledesigns.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=TomcatAntTasks
   --only start/stop application not the actual tomcat itself
4. http://cargo.codehaus.org/Remote+Container
   -- Which does't start/stop tomcat that's running on that server

Comment: Why stop tomcat at all? Use the tomcat manager application to deploy/redeploy the app to a running instance of tomcat. (You've listed a link to the tomcat manager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ssh access to the server, then you might like to consider the [JSch library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) which you can use in combination with [SSHExec Ant Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) to start and stop your server:

```
<sshexec host="somehost"
    username="dude"
    password="yo"
    command="/etc/init.d/tomcat restart"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

***For start/stop tomcat***

In linux environment 
use SSH to reach the terminal of the remote machine.
from the terminal You can start/stop the tomcat

to start    **startup.sh** 
to stop    **shutdown.sh**

Under windows environment

Install OpenSSHD for Windows - this will allow remote "console" sessions.

If you looking for something very "unix-like" then you can install cygwin.

http://www.worldgoneweb.com/2011/installing-openssh-on-windows-7/

to start    **startup.bat** 
to stop    **shutdown.bat**

***For deployment***

Simply go to tomcat manager link on the below page(on any environment)

http://`your_server_ip`:`port_number`/

user credential are specified in tomcat-users.xml inside conf di